# Which dynamic created button was pressed in Servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, scriptlet

I have dynamically created buttons.

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <table cellpadding="4">
        <%
            List<Room> rl = (List<Room>) request.getAttribute("roomList");
            if(rl != null) {
                for (Room r : rl) {
                    String name = r.getName();
        %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=name%></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add a Booking" name=<%=name%> /></td>
            </tr>
        <%
                }
            }
   %>
   </table>
```

I know which button was clicked with the following code;

```
String addButton = req.getParameter("addButton");
```

However, in this situation, I am not able to know the name of the button. Because the name of the button could be anything. How could I know which button was pressed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have only one submit button in your code, so why do you expect more?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it is inside "for (Room r : rl)" loop. There would be one or more

Comment: I see, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly have at least two solutions:

**1. Solution in Java code on the server side**

in JSP each of the submit button will be named with the `submit_` prefix

```
<input type="submit" value="Add a Booking" name=<%="submit_"+name%> />
```

When request is send to the server you will loop parameters and search for one with this prefix, saving its value to `submit` attribute:

```
private void setSubmitValue(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String SUBMIT_PREFIX = "submit_";
  for (Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    String key = (String) e.nextElement();
    if (key.startsWith(SUBMIT_PREFIX)) {
      String value = key.substring(SUBMIT_PREFIX.length());
      request.setAttribute("submit", value);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Solution with JavaScript on the client (browser) side**

Introduce in the form new hidden widget that will hold the number of room clicked. When button is clicked its value is stored in that widget.

When request is send, on the server side you just read the value of that parameter (widget name).

 Below is an example: room-nr will have value of clicked button

```js
var form = document.forms['add-room'];
$(form).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $(this).attr('name')
  form['room-nr'].value = name.replace(/\D+/, '');
  console.log(form['room-nr'].value);
  //form['add-booking'].click();
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="add-room" action='.'">
  <input type="hidden" name="room-nr" value="" />
  <table cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
      <td>room1</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" name="room-1">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>room2</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" name="room-2">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>room3</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" name="room3">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Add a Booking" name="add-booking" class="hide" />
</form>
```

Comment: It works perfect, just one more question. Sometimes, the name attribute gets value with space, for instance; "Room 1". With this value; name attribute is shown as "name="submit_Room" 1". How could I handle it?

Comment: I would advise to encode form data on submit and decrypt on a server side. You can find more about it on Internet i.e [here](http://www.diogogmt.com/temp-slug-108/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

> <input type="submit" value="<%name%>" name="Add Booking"
>   />

Comment: But I would like to know which one is pressed. In this situation; I will get 5 buttons with the same name.

Comment: Unique value <%name%> will tell you that.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine, however, now all the Button's text are nonsense.